# Access to an object of an object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

I'm using Datamaps plugin and I'm trying to access to an object that is in another object.

Here I want to get all the values of `data` in `options`. Please see the console.log answer the screenshot below.

**Here is the js:**

```
var map = new Datamap({
  scope: "fra",
  element: document.getElementById("map-france"),
  responsive: true,
  fills: {
    defaultFill: "#EDE8D6",
    "1-50": color_dept[4],
    "51-100": "#EDE8D6",
    "101-150": "#E2DABF",
    "151-200": "#CEC191",
    "201-300": "#BCAE7C",
    "301-400": "#9D893E",
    "401-": "#827131",
  },
  data: {
    YV: {
      fillKey: "#EDE8D6",
    },
    AM: {
      fillKey: "51-100",
    },
  },
  geographyConfig: {
    popupTemplate: function (geo, data) {
      for (const val of uniqueValues) {
        if (geo.properties.name == val) {
          return [
            '<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>',
            val,
            "<br/>",
            dataValues.filter((v) => v == val).length,
            " parrainages",
            "</strong></div>",
          ].join("");
        }
      }
    },
    hideAntarctica: true,
    hideHawaiiAndAlaska: false,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderOpacity: 1,
    borderColor: "#D2D3B5",
    popupOnHover: true, // True to show the popup while hovering
    highlightOnHover: true,
    highlightFillColor: "#1E2382",
    highlightBorderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    highlightBorderWidth: 1,
    highlightBorderOpacity: 1,
  },
  setProjection: function (element) {
    var projection = d3.geo
      .mercator()
      .center([2.454071, 46.279229])
      .rotate([0, 0])
      .scale(1700)
      .translate([350, 225]);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    return {
      path: path,
      projection: projection,
    };
  },
});


Object.entries(map).map((item) => {
  console.log("item 1 : ", item);
});
```

[image]

Comment: you don't need to use `map()`, can you try logging `map.data`?

Comment: What is a `Datamap`?

Comment: @Rojo it's a plugin for maps

Comment: Could you provide a link to a github repository for it or something?

Comment: @AzizaKasenova, it's undefined : 
`Object.entries(map).map((item) => {
  console.log("item 1 : ", map.data);
});`

Comment: @Rojo, sure : https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps

Comment: Please read [ask], where it says, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: Meryem , the `map` variable is probably not an array , and that is why you cannot run `.map` on it.

Comment: @Zurez, where is the OP using `.map` on the `map` variable? Looks like they are running `.map` on the output of `Object.entries()`, which is indeed an array.

Comment: @Heretic : Yes you are right , my bad. I think I had too much caffeine

Comment: Why not create a separate variable to hold the options (e.g., `var options = {  scope: "fra", ... };`) and call Datamap with that (e.g., `var map = new Datamap(options);`). Then you can access `options` separately whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ex.

```
const mapExample = new Map()

mapExample.set("test", 
{"nestedObj":{"newObject":"new Obj value"}})
```

now, map over this would give you an array with the top level object "test"

to get the value of the nested value of "newObject":

```
Object.entries(mapExample.get("test")).map(i=> console.log(i[1].newObject))
```

or

```
Object.entries(mapExample.get("test")).map(i=> {
  let [key,value] = i
  console.log(key,value)
});
```

can copy and post this into chrome console and mess around with it, to see different outcomes.

but key take way is Object.entries return an array of your Object in ["key":"value"] order.

Comment: it gives me an error : Uncaught TypeError: map.get is not a function

Comment: It was perhaps a bad idea to use the same variable name for your answer's `Map` as the OP's existing `Datamap` variable.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks for your comment, i changed it but the error still here : Uncaught TypeError: mapdata.get is not a function

`Object.entries(mapdata.get("options")).map((i) => {
  let [key, value] = i;
  console.log(key, value);
});`

Comment: Then there's something wrong earlier in the code. Perhaps `Map` has been overridden by some other code and is no longer referencing the standard built in [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object, which has a `get` method, @MeryemACHEMLAL.

Comment: @MeryemACHEMLAL,
in the example I used a Map data structure because i assumed your custom class was of type Map() because how it was named.

but for regular Objects like your example.

if I wanted to get YV's and AM's value:
Object.entries(mapData.data).map(i=> {
  let [key,value] = i
  console.log(value.fillKey)
});

would get you the value